# How can I get this formula to check multiple status codes?

Tags: sql

I want this to count status codes not just 0, but also when the status codes 404, 301, 303 match the same REGEX expression

```
COUNT_DISTINCT(
CASE
WHEN Status Code = 0 AND REGEXP_MATCH(Status,'[Rr]efused|[Rr]esponse|[Dd][Nn][Ss]') THEN Address
ELSE NULL END
)
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.  (3) What is `COUNT_DISTINCT()` ???

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Status Code IN ( 0, 404, 301, 303 ) AND
                         REGEXP_MATCH(Status,'[Rr]efused|[Rr]esponse|[Dd][Nn][Ss]')
                    THEN Address
               END)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should answer your question:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN status_code IN (0, 404, 301, 303 ) AND
                         REGEXP_MATCH(Status,'[Rr]efused|[Rr]esponse|[Dd][Nn][Ss]'
THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```